# How can I insert AJAX output before a target and then hide it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to figure out how I can hide some output inserted before a target element. I'm doing this so that I can animate it later.

This is what I've done so far - but it fails to hide the output when it is inserted before the target!

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxURLvalue,
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){

        if(SetIn=='before') {
            $('.'+followFrom+followFrom2).hide().before(html);
        } else if(SetIn=='prepend') {
            $('.'+followFrom+followFrom2).hide().prepend(html);
        } else if(SetIn=='append') {
            $('.'+followFrom+followFrom2).hide().append(html);
        } else if(SetIn=='after') {
            $('.'+followFrom+followFrom2).hide().after(html);
        } else if(SetIn=='prependto') {
            $('.'+followFrom+followFrom2).hide().prependTo(html);   
        }


        }
    });
```

Comment: More info needed. I do not follow.

Comment: I want to Hide this: $('.'+followFrom+followFrom2).hide().before(html); As you can see i already have the hide() in the code. But it does not hide it? - when the Ajax runs the div appear as it should, if I wanted it to be visible. But i wanted it to be hidden

Comment: If you alert() $('.'+followFrom+followFrom2), do you get a HTML element as a response?

Comment: Yes Then i get: #inside_this4 #ltl_nextTo1 - Which are correct

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're hiding the target element and then inserting some content before it. Presumably what you *want* to do is to insert some content before the target and then *hide the inserted content*.

The straightforward way to do this is to start with the content you're inserting:

```
$(html)
```

...then insert that before the target:

```
$(html).insertBefore('.'+followFrom+followFrom2)
```

...then hide it:

```
$(html).insertBefore('.'+followFrom+followFrom2).hide();
```

To be consistent, you may wish to use this same format for all of your content:

```
    if(SetIn=='before') {
        $(html).insertBefore('.'+followFrom+followFrom2).hide();
    } else if(SetIn=='prepend') {
        $(html).prependTo('.'+followFrom+followFrom2).hide();
    } else if(SetIn=='append') {
        $(html).appendTo('.'+followFrom+followFrom2).hide();
    } else if(SetIn=='after') {
        $(html).insertAfter('.'+followFrom+followFrom2).hide();
    } else if(SetIn=='prependto') {
        // this one doesn't make any sense - prepending the target 
        // to the new elements will remove it from the document entirely!
    }
```

Comment: i get this error in the browser log:[Error] Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 2,1 -> sharedID,langID<div id="ltl_nextTo1" class="ltl_nextTo" style="float:left"><div class=ltl_box"" id="ltl_box"><cop>152<img src="/modules/language_box/pic/language_flags/48/da.png" width="36" height="36" class="langIMG" style="" alt=""/></cop><input type="input" name="ltlID152" id="4/25/152" class="" value="" ></div></div>

Comment: error (jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 4)
 gt (jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 4)
 kt (jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 4)
 ot (jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 4)
 find (jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 5)
 init (jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 4)
 x (jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 4)
 success (add_field.js, line 176)
 l (jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 4)
 fireWith (jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 4)
 k (jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 6)
 (anonym funktion) (jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 6)

Comment: Gonna hazard a guess here that `html` is not exactly valid HTML. Follow each step as presented, and see where the error arises - then check your inputs.